# How can I sum up or collect the data on the same field?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

Hi ABAP users I would like to ask if what process I can make to COLLECT the data on the same field? all I want to do is to sum up or collect the data in dmbtr that belongs to same date, (date field monat) (werks to plant codes)

```
it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-num3 = it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-werks.

it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-num2 = it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-dmbtr.

COLLECT it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 COMPARING ALL FIELDS.

Sort it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 by werks.

LOOP AT it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 into wa_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 WHERE monat = '01'.

    IF wa_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-werks EQ '4030'.

        WRITE:/, AT pos wa_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1-dmbtr. 
             
    ENDIF.
    
ENDLOOP.
```

Any configuration in my codes guys?

Comment: You want to summarize data of one concrete month or by each month (= group them)?

Comment: yes sir how can i make that?

Comment: Yes what? Which of the two options?

Comment: Please provide a complete example, not just some random code snipping.

Comment: sorry sir i mean summarizing it by each month.

Comment: that part of my code sir is for collecting the data by each month.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, you already extended standard `bseg` table with `monat` field, then you should do like this:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1,
        werks TYPE bseg-werks,
        monat TYPE monat,
        dmbtr TYPE bseg-dmbtr,
       END OF ty_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.

DATA: it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 TYPE TABLE OF ty_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1,
      is_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 TYPE ty_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.

SELECT werks, monat, dmbtr
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_bseg)
FROM bseg
WHERE werks = '4030'.

* summation of months
LOOP AT lt_bseg ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_line>).
  CLEAR: is_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.
  MOVE-CORRESPONDING <fs_line> TO is_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.
  COLLECT is_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 INTO it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.
ENDLOOP.

* output the results
LOOP AT it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<zfi_line>).
    IF <zfi_line>-werks EQ '4030'.
        WRITE: / <zfi_line>-werks, <zfi_line>-monat, <zfi_line>-dmbtr.
    ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Couple of notes to your incorrect code:

1. `COLLECT` doesn't work like single statement and should be executed in loop.
2. To sum with `COLLECT` statement you should declare work area so that all non-key fields would be numeric. Key fields (even if it is implicit key) can be of any type, as opposed to what Ray said. `N` type is also OK.
3. `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES` is redundant here, because after `COLLECT` (which makes summation by primary key) you won't have any dups.

Answer (score -1):

This all comes down to how you define your internal table it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1

For COLLECT to work, you need to define it with character type keys followed by packed field types:

data: begin of it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 occurs 0,
        werks      type werks,
        month(2)   type c,
        dmbtr      type dmbtr,
      end of it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1.

That will work.

This will not:

data: begin of it_zfi_vbrp_bseg_1 occurs 0.
include structure vbrp.
data:   monat  type monat,
        dmbtr  type dmbtr,
      end of it_zfi_vbrp_bseg.

Read the help on COLLECT and define your summary table accordingly.

Comment: Sir sorry about this what do you mean in months(2) type c? what is the use of that?

Comment: Not true. `COLLECT` statement will perfectly work with `monat` type which has `n` type.